# What is the difference between ^a|A$ and ^(a|A)$?

Tags: regex

What is the difference between  **`^a|A$`**   and   **`^(a|A)$`**   ?

thanks

Comment: Why not try it out for yourself: regexhero.net (you're going to need IE to see the site unfortunately).

Comment: @briantyler typically https://regex101.com/ is more useful.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. This is a very reasonable question if you have little experience with regular expressions..

Comment: There is definitely a school of thought that this site has a real problem with people jumping in and hammering new users. Don't worry it isn't just you and it isn't just new users. Lots of people who've been using SO for years have got pretty disillusioned with the general attitude. I think the down votes were probably because you hadn't demonstrated that you'd tried to work this out yourself and were stuck and needed some help. (anyway, looks like you are back up to 0 now!)

Comment: @ffledgling thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^a|A$` matches a string that starts with `a` or ends with `A`. This will allow `abcd` and `dcbA` as valid strings.

`^(a|A)$` matches a string that is either `a` or `A`. This value is also captured into a group, that can later be accessed.

The first pattern is often a mistake when creating a pattern that shall check a whole string with some alternations. In those cases `^` and `$` should always be outside a grouping structure for the alternations. One might use a non-capturing group `(?:pattern)` to avoid capturing the values. Some languages also have built-in full-match funtions, that should be prefered for those cases (like pythons re.fullmatch)

Answer (score 1):

```
^a|A$
```

- 1st Alternative  ^a
  matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
  ^ asserts position at start of the string
  a matches the character a literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Alternative A$
  A matches the character A literally (case sensitive)
  $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

  ^(a|A)$
- ^ asserts position at start of the string
     1st Capturing Group (a|A)
     1st Alternative a
     a matches the character a literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Alternative A
     A matches the character A literally (case sensitive)
     $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Comment: You Can Use Online Regular regex tester Site FOr More Regex  : Ex: regex101.com